# Can't start ceph service

Tags: systemd, ceph

I working on CentOS7 and I install ceph by manual build

```
./autogen.sh 
./configure 
make 
make install
```

and manual deploy by follow this link http://ceph.com/docs/master/install/manual-deployment/

but **ceph** doesn't exist in directory **/etc/rc.d/init.d/**

> Failed to issue method call: Unit ceph.service failed to load: No such
>   file or directory

So, I can't start service.

In document of manual deploy it's said I have to use command

`sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/ceph start mon.node1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CentOS7 use `systemd`

So, use command `sudo systemctl start ceph-osd@0` will work!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can run `systemctl status ceph*` as a quick way to show any services on the box or `systemctl list-units --type=service | grep ceph` the service name syntax is `ceph-mon@<hostname>.service` or `ceph-osd@<osd_num>.service`

Answer (score 0):

Please run `systemctl list-unit-files` and you can list all ceph services and you must find OSD number with `ceph osd tree` and put in this command `systemctl status ceph-osd@{OSD_NUM}.target`